# Save Leading Zero HEX into String RFID RC522 Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, string, rfid

I'm using RC522 to read RFID card. All is until if the HEX leading by 0 then i can't save it into String. But if i print it to Serial all is well. Here is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RST_PIN         9
#define SS_PIN          10

String inStringHex = "";

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();
}

void loop() {
  // Look for new cards
  if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
  {
    //Serial.print("Card UID:");
    for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
      Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
      inStringHex += String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
    }

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println(F("Hex normal"));
    Serial.print(inStringHex);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();

    inStringHex = "";
    delay(5000);
  }
}
```

Here is what displayed in serial monitor:
[image]

What i want is the String under "Hex normal" would be "04292e5a" not "4292e5a"

Please anyone help me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX)` means you want to convert number into hexadecimal string repesentation, if you pass 4 as input parameter, it will convert it into "4", not "04". You need to apply similar approach as you have used when printing the value through UART. For example:

```
if (String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10) 
  inStringHex += " ";
inStringHex += String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
```

Personally, I would recommend switching from Strings into static buffers (because arduino has too small memory to use dynamic allocation and there could be issue with running out of memory due to memory fragmentation):

```
char id[16]; 
sprintf(id, "%02x%02x%02x%02x", mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0], mfrc522.uid.uidByte[1], mfrc522.uid.uidByte[2], mfrc522.uid.uidByte[3]);
```

Comment: Hi, i need to save into string because i will it convert it again to decimal. If i use your recommendation, can i still convert it to decimal?

Comment: Yes of course, you will get the same string and for conversion you can use `strtol` with radix 16. But if you only want to convert four bytes into one long int, there is much [simpler way](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=71030.0)

Comment: I will try your suggestion. Thank you sir.

Comment: `unsigned long result = 0;
result |= (long)mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0] << 24; 
result |= (long)mfrc522.uid.uidByte[1] << 16;
result |= (long)mfrc522.uid.uidByte[2] << 8;
result |= (long)mfrc522.uid.uidByte[3];`

Comment: Is d[0] taken from char id[16]?

Comment: I edited the code to match your situation

Comment: Thank you sir. your recommendation worked as what i want.

Answer (score 1):

you can try ;

```
for (byte i=0; i < uidLength; i++)
{
  Serial.print(uid[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : "");
  Serial.print(uid[i], HEX);
  if (uid[i] < 0x10) inStringHex += "0";
      inStringHex += String(uid[i], HEX);
} Serial.println(); Serial.println(inStringHex);
```